# Registration activity freezing on phones

Tags: java, android-activity

I'm stuck at registration page of my app. I've tested it on AVD and it works fine there but it is to be noted that logcat is heavily stormed by system logs.

The scene right now is that when I test my app on phone the login activity works just fine but when I go to registration page the activity freezes & I have no option other than force closing it myself or wait for my phone to ask me if I want to force close it. Here is the code of my registration page.

The activity name is `Enroll.java`

```
package com.example.dell.iblood;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class enroll extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    EditText Name, Passwordone, Passwordtwo, Age,  Address,Phone, Email;
    Button REGISTER, RESET;
    Spinner States,City,Bloodgroup;

    String val = "";


    InputStream is = null;

    String ip = "http://iblood.byethost3.com/spdemo.php";
    String line = null;
    String result = null;
    List<String> list,list1;

    String name;
    String paso;
    String past;
    String age;
    String bgroup;

    int code;
    String add;
    String state;
    String city;
    String phone;
    String email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enroll);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        REGISTER = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Regbutton);
        RESET = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Resbutton);
        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameU);
        Passwordone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passUone);
        Passwordtwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passUtwo);
        Age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageU);
        Bloodgroup = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bgroupU);
        Address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressU);
        States = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.stateU);
        City = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cityU);
        States = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.stateU);
        Phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobU);
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mailU);

        Bloodgroup.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        States.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        City.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        Selectall();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list); // set list into ArrayAdapter
        States.setAdapter(adp); // Set

        SelectBg();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list); // set list into ArrayAdapter
        Bloodgroup.setAdapter(adp3); // Set

        REGISTER.setOnClickListener(this);
        RESET.setOnClickListener(this);



    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        val = States.getSelectedItem().toString();
        selectcity();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1); // set list into ArrayAdapter
        City.setAdapter(adp1);


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

    private void Selectall() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ip);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Webservice 1", e.toString());
        }
        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Webservice 2", e.toString());
        }
        try {

            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject jo = null;

            list = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                list.add(jo.getString("nameofstate"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Webservice 3", e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void selectcity()

    {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city",val));

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://iblood.byethost3.com/cities.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try {

            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject jo = null;

            list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                list1.add(jo.getString("cityname"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Webservice 13", e.toString());
        }
    }
    private void SelectBg() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://iblood.byethost3.com/bloodgroup.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Webservice 1", e.toString());
        }
        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Webservice 2", e.toString());
        }
        try {

            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject jo = null;

            list = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                list.add(jo.getString("Bloodgroup"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Webservice 3", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_enroll, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int i = view.getId();
        name = Name.getText().toString();
        paso = Passwordone.getText().toString();
        past = Passwordtwo.getText().toString();
        age = Age.getText().toString();
        bgroup=Bloodgroup.getSelectedItem().toString();
        add = Address.getText().toString();
        state= States.getSelectedItem().toString();
        city=City.getSelectedItem().toString();
        phone = Phone.getText().toString();
        email = Email.getText().toString();

        switch (i) {
            case R.id.Regbutton:
                insert();

                break;

            case R.id.Resbutton:
                Name.setText(" ");
                Passwordone.setText("");
                Passwordtwo.setText("");
                Age.setText(" ");
                Bloodgroup.setSelection(0);
                Address.setText(" ");
                States.setSelection(0);
                City.setSelection(0);
                Phone.setText(" ");
                Email.setText(" ");
                break;
        }

    }

    public void insert() {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nameU", name));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passUone", paso));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passUtwo", past));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ageU", age));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bloodgroup",bgroup ));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addressU", add));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nameofstate", state));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cityname", city));



        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobU", phone));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mailU", email));

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://iblood.byethost3.com/reg.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 11", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address"+e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 12", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

            if (code == 1) {
                Intent l = new Intent(this, Mainpage.class);
                startActivity(l);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registered  Successfully \n Please Login",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Intent la = new Intent(this, Mainpage.class);
                startActivity(la);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have a feeling that because you're not making your HTTP requests asynchronously, each time you make a request you're blocking the UI thread until you get a response, and if the response doesn't come back then you're app isn't going to respond.

Comment: I'm completely new to android & have been messing up with code since I've started working on this app. I don't know much about it but have an idea of what you're talking about. Can you please elaborate what you're trying to say ? Or it would be very kind of you to tell me where in the code the problem is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @TomRichardson your basic problem is that you are doing time consuming operations on the UI thread of the activity.

As with most modern environments the 'main' thread of your activity should always be available to process user input making your program responsive. If you want to do something time consuming (such as making an HTTP request) you need to do that in a different background thread.

Typically this sequence goes something like this:
1. UI thread pops up a progress spinner to show it's working and starts the task thread.
2. Task thread works and on completion signals the UIthread
3. The UI thread clears the progress spinner and does whatever it needs to next.

If this all sounds a bit complex then try reading up about Android's ASyncTask class which implements most of these bits for you in a direct and easy way to understand.

ASyncTask has serious issues and as your knowledge of android develops you might consider leaving it behind but it is a good easy place to start with a task like yours.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I've done it via AsyncTask & the app seems to be performing normal :)

Comment: Glad it worked out for you - something to keep in mind for the future: If you start multiple async tasks they run one after the other in a queue not in parallel like you might expect.